# Using Shiro Guice with jdbcRealm

Tags: java, jdbc, guice, shiro

I'm new to Guice and Shiro, and i'm trying to use it with my DB (h2).
I've read this : [click](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html)

but as they said it's just working for the users and roles sections, which is useless for me.

My shiro.ini is working, i managed to create user, login and logout without the Guice part.

My MyShiroModule

```
public class MyShiroModule extends ShiroModule{

protected void configureShiro() {
    try {
        bindRealm().toConstructor(IniRealm.class.getConstructor(Ini.class));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        addError(e);
    }
}

@Provides
Ini loadShiroIni() {
    return Ini.fromResourcePath("classpath:shiro.ini");
}
}
```

and my Module :

public class Module extends AbstractModule {

```
@Singleton

protected void configure() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyShiroModule());
    SecurityManager securityManager = injector.getInstance(SecurityManager.class);
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);        
}
}
```

they're as they said in the tutorial.
What do i have to add to use the [main] part of my shiro.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got the JDBC realm to work with Guice since, as you noted, it only reads the users and groups section for whatever reason. I ended up not using Shiro.ini at all just creating the `JdbcRealm` myself like this:

```java
public class ShiroAuthModule extends ShiroModule {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    super.configure();
    // Bind your data source however you need to - I use JNDI 
    // but it would be easy to switch to a properties file.
    bind(Context.class).to(InitialContext.class);
    bind(DataSource.class).toProvider(JndiIntegration.fromJndi(DataSource.class, "java:/comp/env/jdbc/security"));
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  JdbcRealm loadJdbcRealm(Ini ini, DataSource ds, 
      @Named("shiro.authenticationQuery") String authenticationQuery,
      @Named("shiro.userRolesQuery") String roleQuery,
      @Named("shiro.permissionsQuery") String permissionQuery) {
    JdbcRealm realm = new JdbcRealm();
    realm.setAuthenticationQuery(authenticationQuery);
    realm.setUserRolesQuery(roleQuery);
    realm.setPermissionsQuery(permissionQuery);
    realm.setPermissionsLookupEnabled(true);
    realm.setDataSource(ds);
    return realm;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureShiro() {
    // shiro.properties should be on your classpath and 
    // contain the named properties in loadJdbcRealm
    Properties properties = Module.loadProperties(this, "shiro.properties");
    Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);
    try {
      bindRealm().to(JdbcRealm.class);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
      addError(e);
    }
  }

}
```